# QDateedit date changes on mouse press

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QDateEdit and set some date on it .But when i mouse press on date part automatically changes i dont want this behaviour to happen and this happens only when i have the following option on date edit,i want to change the date only when user click on the popup menu or when he edits in line edit part.I have attcahed a video for much better understanding.Any help on the issue is highly appreciated.

```
    QDateEdit *startDateEdit = new QDateEdit;
    QDateEdit *endDateEdit = new QDateEdit;

    startDateEdit->setCalendarPopup(true);
    startDateEdit->setDate(QDate::currentDate());

    endDateEdit->setCalendarPopup(true);
    endDateEdit->setDate(QDate::currentDate());
```

[Sample][1] [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwN_QAti6Sg

Comment: I have tested and the problem is the `setCalendarPopup()` function.

Comment: @jgoros thanks but i require setcalenderpopup() to show calender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As QDateEdit class is inherited from QAbstractSpinBox  you can solve your problem with adding the next *(the problem seems a little bug)*:

```
dateEdit->setButtonSymbols(QAbstractSpinBox::NoButtons);
```